# Log only errors in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How do I make cloudwatch not log any lamba executions unless the process exited with a status greater than 0?

If not possible, how do I prevent lambda from writing any cloudwatch notifications.

Comment: This isn't possible. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I believe cloudwatch is charging us per request which brings up the cost of lambda. If we're running serverless processes getting millions of requests, handling exception tracking from the lambda would be more ideal that cloudwatch catching every single message.

Comment: Also, This lambda is also writing to a kinesis, so I don't really care about anything except errors from cloudwatch.

Comment: This article might be of interest to you. https://hackernoon.com/tips-and-tricks-for-logging-and-monitoring-aws-lambda-functions-885af6da29a5

Comment: You are incorrect about being charged per request. CloudWatch logs charges $0.50 per GB ingested. https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/

Comment: You can remove CloudWatch permissions from the IAM role under which your Lambda runs and use a centralized log server to log to

Comment: @Unglückspilz I can accept this as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove CloudWatch permissions from the IAM role under which your Lambda runs and use a centralized log server to log to.